# Undefined property: Mage_Shell_Compiler::$_factory in indexer.php

Tags: error, indexer

Since SUPEE on Magento 1.9.0.1 we see the following error:

`Notice: Undefined property: Mage_Shell_Compiler::$_factory in /shell/indexer.php on line 45`

Question: Did someone come across this error too? 
`

It is used in this function
`protected function _getIndexer()
    {
        return $this->_factory->getSingleton($this->_factory->getIndexClassAlias());
    }`